# Como "copiar" texto de uma div para outra com JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu tô organizando um player pra por no meu site. Como não sei muito de JS/JQ, peguei um modelo simples na internet, montei um layout e ajustei o script ao meu gosto até onde consegui.

Agora emperrei em uma coisa que achava ser super fácil, mas já tentei de várias formas sem sucesso. O que eu quero é "clonar" o texto que estiver em uma `div` (no caso o nome da música, do `[currentIndex]`) para outra `div` (na barra do player).

Aqui tô deixando a parte do script que considero que tem a possibilidade de fazer isso pra vocês entenderem melhor a lógica dele. Vejam a minha última tentativa:

```
      Carousel.prototype.go_to = function( index, currentIndex )
    {   
if (currentIndex != index) {

    index = index%this.count;
    if (index < 0)
        index = index + this.count;

    this.$.faicha[currentIndex].classList.remove('ativo');
    this.$.faicha[index].classList.add('ativo');

    this.$.musica[0].setAttribute('src', 'som/' + index + '.mp3');

    /*Aqui abaixo minha tentativa*/
    this.$.nomedamusica[0].clone().appendTo(".nomedamusicaaqui");

    this.changeMusic();
    this.index = index;
}
};
```

`.nomedamusica` vem da classe onde tem o nome da música. E `.nomedamusicaaqui` é a classe da `div` onde o texto deve ser "colado".

Comment: Vc quer pegar só o texto ou a div toda?

Comment: apenas o texto! mas a div só tem o texto mesmo

Comment: Tenta `$(".nomedamusicaaqui").append(this.$.nomedamusica[0].text());`

Comment: @dvd funcionou não mano... e parte da função se corrompe :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só pegar o texto do elemento ativo com a classe `.ativa` (música que está selecionada) e jogar dentro da outra `div`, usando:

```
`$(".nomedamusicaaqui").text($("div.ativa").text());`
            ↑                         ↑
       div destino         div de onde virá o texto
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var Player = function ( $target )
{
 this.$ = {};
 this.$.body       = $target;
 this.$.prev     = this.$.body.find('.prev');
 this.$.next       = this.$.body.find('.next');
 this.$.play       = this.$.body.find('.play');
 this.$.seek_bar   = this.$.body.find('.seek-bar');
 this.$.progress_bar  = this.$.body.find('.progress-bar');
 this.$.faichas    = this.$.body.find('.faichas');
 this.$.music   = this.$.body.find('.music');
 this.$.faicha    = this.$.faichas.find('.faicha');

 this.count = this.$.faicha.length;
 this.init_events();
};

Player.prototype.index = 0;
Player.prototype.count = 0;
Player.prototype.progress_ratio = 0;

Player.prototype.init_events = function (){
 var that = this;
 
 this.$.next.on('click', function(){
  that.next();
  return false;
 });
 this.$.prev.on('click', function(){
  that.prev();
  return false;
 });

 this.changeMusic();

 this.$.play.on('click', function(){
  play = !play;
  that.changeMusic();
  return false;
 });
 
 /* ação quando a música acabar */ 
 this.$.music.bind('ended', function(){
  that.next();
 });

 /**** barra de tempo ****/
 window.setInterval(function () {
  this.progress_ratio = that.$.music[0].currentTime / that.$.music[0].duration;
     that.$.progress_bar.css({
    transform: "scaleX(" + progress_ratio + ")"
  });
 }, 50);
 /* Permite alterar a hora atual da música */ 
 this.$.seek_bar.on('click', function (e) {
         var x = e.clientX - that.$.seek_bar.offset().left,
         ratio = x / that.$.seek_bar.width(),
         time = ratio * that.$.music[0].duration;
     that.$.music[0].currentTime = time;
 });
};

Player.prototype.next = function()
{
 this.go_to( this.index + 1, this.index);
};
Player.prototype.prev = function()
{
 this.go_to( this.index - 1, this.index);
};

Player.prototype.go_to = function( index, currentIndex )
{
   
 if (currentIndex != index) { // Evite recomeçar o áudio clicando na música atual

  index = index%this.count;
  if (index < 0)
   index = index + this.count;
  
  this.$.faicha[currentIndex].classList.remove('ativa');
  this.$.faicha[index].classList.add('ativa');
  /* mudar a fonte da música */
  this.$.music[0].setAttribute('src', 'http://audeficheux.com/projects/carousel/src/medias/' + index + '.mp3');
  
  this.changeMusic();
  this.index = index;

      // LINHA ADICIONADA
      $(".nomedamusicaaqui").text($("div.ativa").text());
 }
};

Player.prototype.changeMusic = function()
{ 

 /* Tocar/pausar a música */  
 if (play == true) {
  this.$.play[0].classList.add('pausa');
  this.$.music[0].play();
      
      // LINHA ADICIONADA
    $(".nomedamusicaaqui").text($("div.ativa").text());
   }
 else {
  this.$.play[0].classList.remove('pausa');
  this.$.music[0].pause();
 }
};

var $carousel = new Player( $('body') );
var play = false
```

```css
body {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #212121;
  margin: 0;
  }
  .controls {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  }
  .seek-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  }
  .seek-bar .progress-bar {
  background-color: #1CE8B3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -o-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.2s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  }
  .controls .buttons {
  width: 300px;height: 45px;
  left:0;right:0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  }
  .controls .play{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;height: 50px;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  margin: auto;
  }
  .prev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;top:0;bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  width: 45px;height: 45px;
  }
  .next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;
  width: 45px;height: 45px;
  }
  .faichas .faicha{padding: 10px;}
  .faichas .faicha .name{vertical-align: middle;}
  .faicha {background: #212121;}
  .faicha.ativa {background: #111111;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nomedamusicaaqui">
</div>

 <div class="controls">
  <div class="seek-bar"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="prev">anterior</a>
    <a class="play">tocar/pausar</a>
    <a class="next">proxima</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
   <div class="faichas">  
  <div class="faicha ativa">
   <div class="name">música 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faicha">
   <div class="name">música 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faicha">
   <div class="name">música 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faicha">
   <div class="name">música 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="faicha">
   <div class="name">música 5</div>
  </div>
  <audio class="music"><source src="http://audeficheux.com/projects/carousel/src/medias/0.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser doesn't support video API</audio>
 </div>
```